# Is UX Research most of the time unnecessary nowadays?

Tags: user-research

I got mixed opinions from my colleagues, so I would like your two cents on this.

As we know, UX research is a time-consuming step in the UX process. When you work with apps or websites, I believe that step could be skipped. The reason is simple. There are already several best practices in place. Best practices, guidelines, heuristics evaluation already exist, and they are a time-saver. If you think about it, for example, in every step of a website creation, there are some guidelines/best practices to start with. Besides, there are thousands of apps and websites that can be used as an example of "doing right". So, IMHO, it is faster to look around and see what is working well and "copy" that to our app/website than doing UXR. After that, you can use CRO to know exactly what your customers think about your product and start tweaking it.

My point is that UX research was very important in the begging of the Internet and apps. Now, we have a whole generation that grew up having the Internet and mobiles. And even the parents of that generation know how to use websites and apps. Yes, there are specific cases where UXR is welcome, but I think that doing UXR for every single project may be overkill.

What do you think?

Comment: This isn't a question that can be correctly answered. It's a discussion topic and therefore better suited to a discussion forum, not a Q&A site.

Comment: It depends how complicated an interface is.  If it's complex applying best practice won't catch everything: so you need to test with real users.

Comment: This kind of reminds me of "640K ought to be enough for anybody."

Answer (score 3):

UX research is broader than only usability.

UX research should actually help define what you build so that you don't waste resources building something your customers don't need or want.

Sure, you can build a whole website based off of some other example using the very best usability practices but if the product doesn't provide your customers any value.. well your product is flawed.

Comment: Copying without understanding is a great way to fall into "cargo-cult" thinking which UX can help avoid.